# Using Exit in CodeIgniter output makes the content type header to text/html instead of the defined one

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-type, exit

```
public function jsonExit($array)
{
    $this->con->output->set_content_type('application/json'); // $this->con is get_instance from the constructor
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

This piece of code outputs the data properly in JSON format. But when I include `exit;` in the function, the content type becomes `text/html` instead of `application/json` which I defined.

What is the reason? And with what I can replace the `exit`? In this case `return` will not work as it stops only executing this function `jsonExit` anymore. But it will continue to run the script from where I call the jsonExit function. My task is to EXIT completely.

Comment: try `die();`, that should stop the execution of the script if that is what you desire.

Comment: Why would you include `exit`? jsonExit could return a `false` when you want it to exit, then the controller or whatever calls this function could check `if (! jsonExit($array)) { die(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using directly the `echo`.

Instead use the `set_output`. [Docs here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_output)

```
public function jsonExit($array)
{
    $this->con->output->set_content_type('application/json'); // $this->con is get_instance from the constructor
    $this->con->output->set_output(json_encode($array));
}
```

If you need the `exit`or `die`use `_display`. [Docs here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::_display)

> This method is called automatically at the end of script execution, you won’t need to call it manually unless you are aborting script execution using exit() or die() in your code.

```
public function jsonExit($array)
{
    $this->con->output->set_content_type('application/json'); // $this->con is get_instance from the constructor
    $this->con->output->_display(json_encode($array));
    exit(0);
}
```

Or as it is used in the [example](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::_display)